# Receiving multiple webhook notifications for every Office 365 event update

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a sync server that keeps the Office 365 events and my calendering app in sync

I subscribed to a push notification for user's event calendar that has the following custom single extended property.

Sample subscription request payload

```
{
   "resource": "/me/events?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'\''String%20{66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00047ec6ac6e}%20Name%20CUSTOM'\'')",
   "notificationUrl": "https://serverurl.xxxx.com/dev/notification",  
   "changeType": "updated,created",
   "clientState": "123456-fad3-4191-9a66-123456789",
   "expirationDateTime": "2018-03-17T11:00:00.0000000Z"
}
```

Then I do a single update of calendar event that has the above custom single extended property. On update, the sync server receives multiple notifications (2-3 notifications) for just updating the title of the event.

Notification 1:

```
{
    "value": [{
        "subscriptionId": "9645fed8-dc53-4955-b3a1-2d2b9ac5728f",
        "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2018-03-17T11:00:00+00:00",
        "changeType": "updated",
        "resource": "<masked>",
        "resourceData": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Event",
            "@odata.id": "<masked>",
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"+JK7q7qG1U+aBgDQ2ypjIQAAVnP6yQ==\"",
            "id": "AAMkAGJmZjA5NzI0LWM5NTgtNGRhYy04MDExLTJmZTY4ZTJkNmVlYQBGAAAAAAC-F40EZzuzSqgA9N8VQW0zBwD4kruruobVT5oGANDbKmMhAAAAAAENAAD4kruruobVT5oGANDbKmMhAABV-OaMAAA=",
            "createdDateTime": "2018-03-13T13:30:54.740501Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-13T13:42:33.7107864Z",
            "changeKey": "+JK7q7qG1U+aBgDQ2ypjIQAAVnP6yQ==",
            "categories": [],
            "originalStartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "originalEndTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000006474883CFBAD30100000000000000001000000021D57F3032480543BE96AE56D8816FDF",
            "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
            "isReminderOn": true,
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "subject": "Microsoft DEMO - 2 UPDATED",
            "bodyPreview": "Let's get together!",
            "importance": "Normal",
            "sensitivity": "Normal",
            "isAllDay": false,
            "isCancelled": false,
            "isOrganizer": true,
            "responseRequested": true,
            "seriesMasterId": null,
            "showAs": "Busy",
            "type": "SingleInstance",
            "webLink": "<masked>",
            "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
            "responseStatus": {
                "Response": "Organizer",
                "Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "body": {
                "ContentType": "HTML",
                "Content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\nLet's get together!\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
            },
            "start": {
                "DateTime": "2018-03-29T01:00:00Z",
                "TimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Utc"
            },
            "end": {
                "DateTime": "2018-03-29T06:00:00Z",
                "TimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Utc"
            },
            "location": {
                "DisplayName": "",
                "LocationType": "Default",
                "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                "Address": {
                    "Type": "Unknown"
                },
                "Coordinates": {}
            },
            "locations": [],
            "recurrence": null,
            "attendees": [{
                "Type": "Required",
                "Status": {
                    "Response": "None",
                    "Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "EmailAddress": {
                    "Name": "<masked>",
                    "Address": "<masked>"
                }
            }],
            "organizer": {
                "EmailAddress": {
                    "Name": "<masked>",
                    "Address": "<masked>"
                }
            }
        },
        "clientState": "123456-fad3-4191-9a66-123456789"
    }]
}
```

Notification 2:

```
{
    "value": [{
        "subscriptionId": "9645fed8-dc53-4955-b3a1-2d2b9ac5728f",
        "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2018-03-17T11:00:00+00:00",
        "changeType": "updated",
        "resource": "<masked>",
        "resourceData": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Event",
            "@odata.id": "<masked>",
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"+JK7q7qG1U+aBgDQ2ypjIQAAVnP6yw==\"",
            "id": "AAMkAGJmZjA5NzI0LWM5NTgtNGRhYy04MDExLTJmZTY4ZTJkNmVlYQBGAAAAAAC-F40EZzuzSqgA9N8VQW0zBwD4kruruobVT5oGANDbKmMhAAAAAAENAAD4kruruobVT5oGANDbKmMhAABV-OaMAAA=",
            "createdDateTime": "2018-03-13T13:30:54.740501Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-13T13:42:33.869926Z",
            "changeKey": "+JK7q7qG1U+aBgDQ2ypjIQAAVnP6yw==",
            "categories": [],
            "originalStartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "originalEndTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "iCalUId": "<masked>",
            "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
            "isReminderOn": true,
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "subject": "Microsoft DEMO - 2 UPDATED",
            "bodyPreview": "Let's get together!",
            "importance": "Normal",
            "sensitivity": "Normal",
            "isAllDay": false,
            "isCancelled": false,
            "isOrganizer": true,
            "responseRequested": true,
            "seriesMasterId": null,
            "showAs": "Busy",
            "type": "SingleInstance",
            "webLink": "<masked>",
            "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
            "responseStatus": {
                "Response": "Organizer",
                "Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "body": {
                "ContentType": "HTML",
                "Content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\nLet's get together!\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
            },
            "start": {
                "DateTime": "2018-03-29T01:00:00Z",
                "TimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Utc"
            },
            "end": {
                "DateTime": "2018-03-29T06:00:00Z",
                "TimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Utc"
            },
            "location": {
                "DisplayName": "",
                "LocationType": "Default",
                "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                "Address": {
                    "Type": "Unknown"
                },
                "Coordinates": {}
            },
            "locations": [],
            "recurrence": null,
            "attendees": [{
                "Type": "Required",
                "Status": {
                    "Response": "None",
                    "Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "EmailAddress": {
                    "Name": "<masked>",
                    "Address": "<masked>"
                }
            }],
            "organizer": {
                "EmailAddress": {
                    "Name": "<masked>",
                    "Address": "<masked>"
                }
            }
        },
        "clientState": "123456-fad3-4191-9a66-123456789"
    }]
}
```

Notification 3:

```
{
    "value": [{
        "subscriptionId": "9645fed8-dc53-4955-b3a1-2d2b9ac5728f",
        "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2018-03-17T11:00:00+00:00",
        "changeType": "updated",
        "resource": "<masked>",
        "resourceData": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Event",
            "@odata.id": "<masked>",
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"+JK7q7qG1U+aBgDQ2ypjIQAAVnP6yw==\"",
            "id": "AAMkAGJmZjA5NzI0LWM5NTgtNGRhYy04MDExLTJmZTY4ZTJkNmVlYQBGAAAAAAC-F40EZzuzSqgA9N8VQW0zBwD4kruruobVT5oGANDbKmMhAAAAAAENAAD4kruruobVT5oGANDbKmMhAABV-OaMAAA=",
            "createdDateTime": "2018-03-13T13:30:54.740501Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-13T13:42:33.869926Z",
            "changeKey": "+JK7q7qG1U+aBgDQ2ypjIQAAVnP6yw==",
            "categories": [],
            "originalStartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "originalEndTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "iCalUId": "<masked>",
            "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
            "isReminderOn": true,
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "subject": "Microsoft DEMO - 2 UPDATED",
            "bodyPreview": "Let's get together!",
            "importance": "Normal",
            "sensitivity": "Normal",
            "isAllDay": false,
            "isCancelled": false,
            "isOrganizer": true,
            "responseRequested": true,
            "seriesMasterId": null,
            "showAs": "Busy",
            "type": "SingleInstance",
            "webLink": "<masked>",
            "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
            "responseStatus": {
                "Response": "Organizer",
                "Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "body": {
                "ContentType": "HTML",
                "Content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\nLet's get together!\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
            },
            "start": {
                "DateTime": "2018-03-29T01:00:00Z",
                "TimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Utc"
            },
            "end": {
                "DateTime": "2018-03-29T06:00:00Z",
                "TimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Utc"
            },
            "location": {
                "DisplayName": "",
                "LocationType": "Default",
                "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                "Address": {
                    "Type": "Unknown"
                },
                "Coordinates": {}
            },
            "locations": [],
            "recurrence": null,
            "attendees": [{
                "Type": "Required",
                "Status": {
                    "Response": "None",
                    "Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "EmailAddress": {
                    "Name": "<masked>",
                    "Address": "<masked>"
                }
            }],
            "organizer": {
                "EmailAddress": {
                    "Name": "<masked>",
                    "Address": "<masked>"
                }
            }
        },
        "clientState": "123456-fad3-4191-9a66-123456789"
    }]
}
```

I expected just one notification for every update (In my case I just did an update on event title), but the server is receiving multiple notifications with just @odata.etag different in the notifications. Is this expected?

Comment: I only see a single notification for the `update`. Could you provide an example of "multiple notifications"?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I updated the description with multiple notifications

Comment: Just to clarify, you are receiving 3 notifications for 1 update request. The 1st notification has a different `etag` and `lastModifiedDateTime` than the 2nd and 3rd while the 2nd and 3rd are identical?

Comment: I tried the flow again , `@odata.etag` and `lastModifiedDateTime`  are different for all notifications.

Comment: Are there by chance any Outlook Rules or other automation apps watching the calendar? The different modification time implies that you made an update and another app(s) came in an automatically applied a change of some kind.

Comment: I don't think there are any outlook rules or automation apps using my calendar. Is there a way I can check if there are any?

I'm not sure if this helps - I tried a new subscription for updated and deleted change type and the server received update notifications when the event was created and deleted which was not expected.

Answer (score 1):

When making a change to any item, the server may need to perform several modifications on the item, as well as other related items behind the scenes. Each of these modifications would result in a notification. There also could be other entities that are listening to changes, and reacting to them, potentially causing further changes and hence more notifications on the item. So in short, there is no guarantee regarding the number of notifications that you may receive as a result of a single API call. That is specially true for high-level calendaring operations, which often involve complex workflows on the server.

In this case you can see that in fact you have received three different change keys, indicating that the item has been modified multiple times.